# The acceleration of a particle is given by $a=(3x+1) ms^{-2}$. Find its velocity after 3 s.

Tags: calculus

The acceleration of a particle is given by $a=(3x+1) ms^{-2}$. If the particle is initially at the origin and moving with velocity of $14 ms^{-1}$.
Find its velocity after 3 s.

I have found the velocity equation as $\frac{dx}{dt} = \sqrt{3x^2+2x+15}$ and so $\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3x^2+2x+15}}$. But how do I integrate this or am I doing the whole question wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you mean $\frac{dv}{dt} = 3x +1$ so $v = \frac{3x^2}{2} + x + C$. Note that $v(0) = 14$ so solve for $C$. Now find $v(3)$.

Comment: Yeah sorry But isn't that substituting x = 3 which is displacement not time?

Comment: Oops I didn't realize $a$ was a function of $x$ and not $t$.

Comment: @OsamaGhani $a$ is implicitly a function of $t$ as $a=a(x(t))$.

Answer (score 3):

You're given that $\displaystyle \frac{dv}{dt} = 3x+1$

At this point, manipulate the LHS with Chain Rule:

$\displaystyle \frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = 3x + 1$

$\displaystyle v\frac{dv}{dx} = 3x+1$

At this point, this becomes a simple separable differentiable equation. Solve as follows:

$\displaystyle \int_{14}^{v_f}vdv = \int_0^{x_f}(3x+1)dx$

where $v_f$ and $x_f$ are final velocity and displacement respectively.

$\displaystyle \frac 12(v_f^2 - 196) = \frac{3x_f^2}{2} + x_f$

Since $\displaystyle \int_{14}^{v_f} v(t)dt = x(t)$, the fundamental theorem of calculus gives $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt} = v_f$

So $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt} = \sqrt{3x^2 + 2x + 196}$

Your expression was different in the constant term - I think you might have made an error somewhere leading up to this. Check your work.

From this point on, solve by separation and completing the square:

$\displaystyle \int_0^{x_f}\frac {dx}{\sqrt{(x + \frac 13)^2 + \frac{196}{3} - \frac 19}} = \int_0^{t_f} \sqrt 3dt$

Do a tangent or inverse hyperbolic sine substitution to integrate the LHS.

Finally find $x_f$ for $t_f$ (final time) equals $3s$ and use that to find $v_f$ in the previously derived equation.